# Issue with sending data to PHP from JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send data from Jquery to PHP. This is what I have:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(dataArray);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addcar_details.php",
                data: {data : jsonArray},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("sent");
                }
            });
```

I am trying to see what I have got in the "$_POST" from the  "addcar_details.php" file. It is empty and I am not sure what I am missing for this to be working.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `method: 'POST'`

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "addcar_details.php",
    data: {'data' : jsonArray},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("sent");
        console.log(data);

    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("there was some error");
    }
});
```

[Read more here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I tried this, and now I don't even get the console.log() so assuming its failing

Comment: You can add the `error` callback. Check the update in my answer.

Comment: And if you are using the `console.log` - you better check the `network` tab in the developers tool bar to see what exactly was the request and what the server's response was. Are you sure your `php` file is not the problem here?

Comment: So it is going in the error, I checked the network tab and it is posting the array and looks fine. All i have in the php file is just a echo to see what's in the post "$_POST"

Comment: Are you sure the response from the server is a valid json string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126448/discussion-between-jomin-george94-and-dekel).

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way

```
var jsonArray = {field1:'Field 1 Value',field2:'Field 2 Value'};

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "addcar_details.php",
    data: jsonArray,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```